# How to add text into summernote editor by clicking a button(Not in toolbar) using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, summernote

I am using angular-summernote in my application. And I am new to FE technologies.

I have to add html element/text by clicking a button(which is not in a summernote toolbar) using angularjs.

I referred [this][1] demo and did some changes and its works on JQuery. 
Updated [demo][2].

But I have to do the same in angularJS.

could someone help on this?

Thanks in advance.

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/ypweuw1L
[2]: http://jsfiddle.net/ManikandanVS/ypweuw1L/20/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directive for your button and use `summernote.createRange()` on button click to create a range object of the selection.

Then you can use `.toString()` to get the selected text and append your new style with `string.substring` on `$scope.text` variable.

`so` and `eo` of range object (start pos. and end pos.) can be used to replace the selected text.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/q46bwktz/).

There is a small bug in the demo. If you remove the span text completely the markup will remain in `$scope` variable.
That could probably be fixed with a watch on the text but not sure how to do it exactly.

Another point could be improved and that's that the selection is removed after applying the new style.

But the demo should help you getting started with your button code.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['summernote'])
 .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
   console.log('Main started');
   $scope.text = 'Hello there';
    
    $scope.options = {
    };
  })
  .directive('stylingPlugin', function() {
   return {
     template: '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addStyle()">Make Note</button>',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.addStyle = function() {
         var $summer = $('#summernote'),
              range = $summer.summernote('createRange'),
             spn = $('<span/>').text(range.toString()).addClass('snote');
          //console.log(range);
          
          scope.text = scope.text.substring(0, range.so) + spn[0].outerHTML
           +scope.text.substring(range.eo, scope.text.length);
            
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.snote {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="demoApp">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/summernote/summernote/v0.7.0/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.5.1/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/summernote/angular-summernote/master/dist/angular-summernote.js"></script>
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <summernote id="summernote" ng-model="text" config="options"></summernote>
    {{text}}
    <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" type="button" ng-click="count = count + 1">Save</button>
    <styling-plugin></styling-plugin>
  </div>
</body>
```